# How to dealloc NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, storyboard, nsmutablearray

I've two `UIViewController` and in the `prepareForSegue` method I want to pass a `NSMutableArray` between it.

Actually I do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

        MySecondVC *secondVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        secondVC.myArray = [[MyClass alloc] getSomeItemsFromDB];

    }
}
```

Now the problem is that `myArray` is very big and after three push and pop I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/A29F6321-4C1C-4DA4-AC4E-EDA5FF7F96F5/TrainingTime2.app> (loaded)' with name 'Wx6-7E-i1q-view-mNF-OU-Ouz' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
([...])
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I guess this is because I'm using too much memory, is that so?

I've also tried to fetch the data from my db in the `viewDidLoad` method but the result is the same.

Any suggestions?

The array contains about 15 items.
The size that I find with this method is 616 but I don't know if it has been properly calculated.

```
size_t size = class_getInstanceSize([EsercizioPerScheda class]);
for (id obj in self.listaEsercizi) {
    size += class_getInstanceSize([obj class]);
}

NSLog(@"%zu", size);
```

I have tried this

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self setMyArray:nil];

}
```

but nothing has changed.

I have fixed this question with some improvements on my query and now the app crash after 20/25 push and pop but I would like to learn how to prevent this kind of issues.

Can any of you suggest some tutorial about how to correctly pass data between view controllers, declare array etc?

Comment: [self setMyArray:nil]; - this statement you can use, or you can create a weak reference of your property, but you need to be sure once it is fully used in MySecondVC class, moving this method in MySecondVC class is better idea, you need to show some more code for further help;

Comment: How many items are in myArray? How big is the average element?

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to be called by the array.

And you don't deallocate objects in Objective-C. You remove references to them, and the object gets deallocated automatically when the last reference is gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using too much memory then I would suggest you populate only those rows of the table view that are needed.

You therefore need to build the database-querying infrastructure into your tableview datasource methods and fetch only those rows you require.  You probably want to include a small amount of caching to avoid hitting the database too frequently.

You will need to use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses to fetch the subset of data required (perhaps rounding up get a page worth in order to improve performance).  Also don't be opening/closing the database for each query, as that will kill performance.

This will obviously increase the complexity of the app (by a lot), but that is what happens in limited-memory environments, and cannot be avoided.

Comment: I think this is not my case because my array contains about 15 items and my tableview can display about 12 row, anyway thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see how much memory your app is consuming by using Instruments. You can find out more about how to use that here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Once you've profiled your app in Instruments you'll be able to determine whether it is your array causing the problem or something else.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be because array is too big. If you passing the same NSMutableArray around you just passing pointer to the same array. I think the reason is you use alloc without init: [[MyClass alloc] getSomeItemsFromDB];